# Dataframes to EdgeRDD (GraphX) using Scala api to Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Is there a nice way of going from a Spark `DataFrame` to an `EdgeRDD` without hardcoding types in the Scala code? The examples I've seen use case classes to define the type of the `EdgeRDD`.

Let's assume that our Spark `DataFrame` has `StructField` `("dstID", LongType, false)` and `("srcID", LongType, false)` and between 0 and 22 additional `StructField` (We are constraining this so that we can use a TupleN to represent them). Is there a clean way to define an `EdgeRdd[TupleN]` by grabbing the types from the `DataFrame`? As motivation, consider that we are loading a Parquet file that contains type information.

I'm very new to Spark and Scala, so I realize the question may be misguided. In this case, I'd appreciate learning the "correct" way of thinking about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to accomplish this would be to map over the Row objects in the Dataframe (with `map`) and return that way.